# Scheduler Job not running in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, resque-scheduler

I have a rails app where an order is assigned to a vendor and the vendor has to accept the order within the next 15 minutes (for test purpose, I am keeping it to two minutes).Once the order is assigned to a vendor, status attribute in the order-assignment table for orders and vendors is updated to assigned. Now the vendor has to accept or reject the order based on which the status is updated to accepted and rejected respectively. If the vendor does not accepts/rejects the order in the next 15 minutes from the time of assignment, the status is automatically updated to rejected in the order-assignment table. Here are the snippets

OrderAssignment model:

```
class Estamps::OrderAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :vendor, class_name: 'Estamps::Vendor'
belongs_to :order, class_name: 'Estamps::Order'
belongs_to :status, class_name: 'Estamps::OrderAssignments::Status'


after_save :enqueue_check_status 

def enqueue_check_status 
   AutoRejectionJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).perform_later(self.id)
   if self.status_id == 3
    OnRejectionJob.perform_later(self.id)
   end
end

end
```

Order model:

```
has_many :order_assignments
belongs_to :vendor
```

Vendor Model:

```
has_many :order_assignments
has_many :orders
```

Auto_rejection_job

```
class AutoRejectionJob < ActiveJob::Base
queue_as :auto_rejection

def perform(order_assignment_id)
    order_assignment = Estamps::OrderAssignment.find(order_assignment_id) 
    if order_assignment 
         if order_assignment.status_id == 1 
             order_assignment.update_attribute('status_id', '3')
             order_assignment.save!
         end  
    end
end
end
```

OrderAssignment schema:

```
 create_table "estamps_order_assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "vendor_id"
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.integer  "status_id"
 end
```

Here the status_id comes from another table which contains various statuses.

Now after creation of an order assignment record, where the status is initially assigned(status_id: 1), if the vendor does not updates the status, then the status_id is automatically updated to status_id:3(rejected). This I tried achieving in the auto_rejection_job. But although, the job is showed as enqued, the status_id is not updated. The job did run correctly when I ran it on console as

```
AutoRejectionJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).**perform_now**(an id),
```

then the status_id is updated, but does not work for the specified scheduled time.Where am I going wrong? HOw can I achieve this? Newbie to rails, so please help.

Comment: You don't have to save model after update_attribute.

Comment: @AleksanderLopez - I will edit that thank you. Can you help me with the main problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't started the worker process. As described in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html, you can configure a bunch of different queuing backends.

If you want to use Sidekiq, add the sidekiq gem

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

run 'bundle' to install

Set up sidekiq as the backend

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Be sure to have the adapter's gem in your Gemfile
    # and follow the adapter's specific installation
    # and deployment instructions.
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```

The you need to have sidekiq running aside your rails server

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq
```

Comment: Actually, I do have resque_scheduler running aside my server

Comment: Could you post the resque log then?

Comment: I tried using sidekiq gem and followed the same steps you mentioned. Nothing seems to change there though.

Comment: I checked my resque log, the auto_rejection_job has not been called there at all. I have redis-server running along with it as well

Comment: Still think the resque logs would be great to have for debugging. - Do you have other jobs running, or is this the first one added? - Did you specify your queue_adapter?